# Centralize similar data from databases in remote locations B thru L to a database at location A

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, triggers, database

I will try to give as many details specific to the scenario as I can.

**Location(s) B thru L =** "REMOTE" databases. Each remote database has just 1 table and the table schema across all locations are identical. Every night at midnight, each remote database purges all records from it's 1 table and inserts new scanned data specific to its location. The table in each remote database will have more than 2 million rows.

The table in each remote database looks like this:

```
field_a   |   field_b   |   field_c
_______________________________________
asdfasd   |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd
asdfasf   |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf
asdfasg   |   asdfasg   |   asdfasg
```

**Location A =** "CENTRAL" database. Will have 1 table with a similar schema to the table in all remote locations with the exception for an additional field that will store the name of the location. This table, which centralizes data from all remote locations, will have more than 25 million rows.

So in theory, the table in Location A (central database) should look like this:

```
location_name   |   field_a   |   field_b   |   field_c
_____________________________________________________________
Location_A      |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd
Location_A      |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf
Location_A      |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd
........
........
Location_B      |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf
Location_B      |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd
Location_B      |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf
........
........
Location_C      |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd
Location_C      |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf
Location_C      |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd
........
........
Location_D      |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf
Location_D      |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd   |   asdfasd
Location_D      |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf   |   asdfasf
........
........
and so on for all locations......
```

Questions for the StackOverflow experts:

- Which database software would you recommend? MySQL? MongoDB?
- How would you configure this? Replication, triggered inserts / updates, etc.

Comment: What find of queries are going to go to the different locations? Is the central server just for backup?

Comment: The goal is to query the master data list, which is: data from all remote locations. So the intent here is to populate the central database with records from all remote locations. The central database becomes the master data list.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really any out-of-the-box way to do this with mongodb. People do it but they generally write their own replication tasks for this. What you could do is run a replica set (for data redundancy) as your remote databases and then write some tasks to query the remote databases and insert/upsert to the central database.